# Model ignoring HasPrecision property

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.NET MVC5 application that is used to uploaded data from a CSV file into a SQL Server 2008 R2 database table.

I have a model,

```
public partial class SURCH
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(30)]
    [Display(Name = "Alloy")]
    public string ALLOY { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Effetive Start Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EFFECTIVE_START_DATE { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2, TypeName = "date")]
    [Display(Name = "Efective End Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime EFFECTIVE_END_DATE { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Cost")]
    public decimal COST { get; set; }
}
```

In my DBContext class, I set the precision of the decimal field COST:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=string")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<SURCH> SURCH { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<SURCH>()
            .Property(e => e.COST)
            .HasPrecision(38, 4);
    }
}
```

When I import my CSV file, I iterate through the rows and create an instance of this model for each row. The COST field in the CSV can be up to 4 decimal places. When I create the instance of the model, the COST field in the model does have the correct precision. However, when I add the model to my table, the COST field is always truncated to 2 decimal places.

Here is how I am adding my list of models to the database.

```
foreach (SURCH currentItem in SURCHlist)
{
    db.SURCH.Add(currentItem);
}

await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Why is my data being truncated? I thought that the HasPrecision property would handle this.

I've already tried a few things. I tried extending the DbConfiguration class and specifying that it should not truncate decimals. I saved this file as DBContextConfiguration in the same folder as my DBContext class file.

```
public class DbContextConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public DbContextConfiguration()
    {
        var providerInstance = SqlProviderServices.Instance;
        SqlProviderServices.TruncateDecimalsToScale = false;
        this.SetProviderServices(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlProviderServices.Instance);
    }
}
```

I also tried manipulating the HasPrecision property and specifying the decimal precision using the TypeName field on the model to no avail.

EDIT1:

Example input data from CSV:

```
1008M,1/1/1900,1/1/1900,0.119
100CRMO7,1/1/1900,1/1/1900,5.001
```

Example output data from Database:

```
1008M       1/1/1900    1/1/1900    0.12
100CRMO7    1/1/1900    1/1/1900    5.00
```

EDIT2:
My database table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SURCH](
    [ALLOY] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE_START_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EFFECTIVE_END_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [COST] [decimal](38, 4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ALLOY] ASC,
    [EFFECTIVE_START_DATE] ASC,
    [EFFECTIVE_END_DATE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after realizing there were two separate issues:

1) My Model was not recognizing the HasPrecision property. After some looking around, I found an article that explained how to create your own DataAnnotation to specify precision. [In this article](https://www.itworld.com/article/2909612/working-with-decimal-precision-in-net-with-mssql-server-and-entity-framework.html), the author had an additional line in their OnModelCreating function in the DbContext class. I added this line into my function and suddenly everything was saving correctly to the database.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Added this line.
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<SURCH>()
        .Property(e => e.COST)
        .HasPrecision(38, 4);
}
```

2) My View was not displaying the correct format. I had assumed that since the database and model were using a precision of 4 decimal places, my view would automatically do the same. Instead, it was showing the default 2 decimal places. To correct this, I added a DataAnnotation to my model to format my COST field to 4 decimal places, including in edit mode.

```
[Display(Name = "Cost")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n4}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public decimal COST { get; set; }
```